# Protect Sub Folder using Web.config file?

Tags: asp.net

i have one subfolder called MySubFolder in my web form project and i want that all the page in that folder will be protected by form authentication. so i search google to do it. i got a xml snippet which i need to put in my main web.config file. the xml snippet as follows

```
<location path="MySubFolder">
            <system.web>
                    <authorization>
                            <deny users="?"/>
                    </authorization>
            </system.web>
    </location>
```

so i want to know that does it protect all files in my subfolder? plzz let me know. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it protects all folder content. And sub-folders' content too (except case when you allow access to sub-folder manually). I.e. with you configuration and next project structure

[image: project structure]

only authorized users will have access both to `MySubFolder/Test.aspx` and `MySubFolder/MySubFolder2/Test2.aspx`.